# How do migrating geese handle hurricanes?

Tags: evolution, ornithology, adaptation, migration

I live on the East coast of the United States, where we are in hurricane season. This week during my morning bike rides in Charlotte, North Carolina, I have seen migrating Canadian geese.

I'm curious if migrating geese have any adaptations for sensing and dealing with hurricanes? Do they treat it like any other rain and wait it out or are there observations of them avoiding a storm?

Here is the range of the Canada Goose.

[image: Canada Goose Migration Map]

[image: Hurricane Harvey]

Comment: Do geese migrate far enough south during hurricane season, so that they'd be likely to encounter hurricanes?

Comment: yes. I see them overhead now and there is a hurricane coming my way.

Comment: Are they actually migrating, or just flying around?  It seems way too early for migration.  And would they have specific adaptations for hurricanes, as opposed to storms in general?

Comment: Strongly related [question](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/23208/where-do-migratory-birds-go-when-it-rains&ved=0ahUKEwjgy6vZ14PWAhVFZVAKHR0ZCfUQFggcMAA&usg=AFQjCNED62w31BLmu05vD4wHkwkNc7t6RQ)